# enumerate is iterating of letters of strings in a list instead of elements

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I'm trying to use `enumerate` to iterate of a list and store the elements of the list as well as use the index to grab the index of another list the same size.

Using a silly example:

```
animal = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish' , 'monkey']
name = ['george', 'steve', 'john', 'james']

x = []
for count, i in enumerate(animal):
    y = zip(name[count], i)
    x = x +y
```

Instead of producing tuples of each element of both lists.  It produces tuples by letter.  Is there a way to do this but get the elements of each list rather than each letter? I know there is likely a better more pythonic way of accomplishing this same task, but I'm specifically looking to do it this way.

Comment: `enumerate()` is **not** iterating over letters. `zip()` on the other hand, is.

Comment: `name[count]` is one of the strings 'george', 'steve', etc. Strings are iterable. What do you expect this code to do?

Comment: I think you just need `zip(animal, name)`, or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enumerate()` is doing no such thing. You are pairing up the letters here:

```
y = zip(name[count], i)
```

For example, for the first element in `animal`, `count` is `0` and `i` is set to `'cat'`. `name[0]` is `'george'`, so you are asking Python to `zip()` together `'george'` and `'cat'`:

```
>>> zip('george', 'cat')
[('g', 'c'), ('e', 'a'), ('o', 't')]
```

This is capped at the shorter wordlength.

If you wanted a tuple, just use:

```
y = (name[count], i)
```

and then *append* that to your `x` list:

```
x.append(y)
```

You *could* use `zip()` instead of `enumerate()` to create your pairings:

```
x = zip(name, animal)
```

without any loops required:

```
>>> animal = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish' , 'monkey']
>>> name = ['george', 'steve', 'john', 'james']
>>> zip(name, animal)
[('george', 'cat'), ('steve', 'dog'), ('john', 'fish'), ('james', 'monkey')]
```

Comment: This is perfect, will accept it once SO allows me to! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `zip()` it actually creates a list of tuples of corresponding elements at each index.

So when you provide `strings` as the input, it provides the result as list of tuples at each character. Example -

```
>>> zip('cat','george')
[('c', 'g'), ('a', 'e'), ('t', 'o')]
```

This is what you are doing, when you iterate over each element in the list and use zip.

Instead , you should directly use `zip` , without iterating over the elements of the list.

Example -

```
>>> animal = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish' , 'monkey']
>>> name = ['george', 'steve', 'john', 'james']
>>> zip(animal,name)
[('cat', 'george'), ('dog', 'steve'), ('fish', 'john'), ('monkey', 'james')]
```